# sql server shred xml with multiple nodes in one query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I'm having trouble shredding this xml in sql server due to the different levels of nodes in the xml. How can I acheieve this with 1 query. Example of the xml below.

```
<Report>
<P>
    <Data>
             <Cust custID = "A" custName = "B" ></Cust>
 </Data>
</P>
<H>
    <Data1>
        <Seats>
            <Seat id = "abc" value = "123" ></Seat>
            <Date depart = "abc1" arrive = "1231" ></Date>
            <Records>
                <Record  recID = "C" col2 = "D" ></Record>
            </Records>
        </Seats>
        <Seats>
            <Seat id = "xyz" value = "756" ></Seat>
            <Date depart = "asd" arrive = "6781" ></Date>
            <Records>
                <Record  recID = "1" col2 = "6" ></Record>
                <Record  recID = "2" col2 = "7" ></Record>
            </Records>
        </Seats>
     </Data1>
    <Data2>
        <S id = "1" value = "eco" ></S>
        <S id = "2" value = "bus" ></S>
    </Data2>
    <Data3>
        <Guest id = "100" value = "aaa" recID="C"></Guest>
        <Guest id = "101" value = "bbb" recID="1"></Guest>
        <Guest id = "102" value = "ccc" recID="2"></Guest>
    </Data3>
 </H>
 </Report>
```

Comment: the end tag </Report> was cut off for some reason

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about *how* you want to shred the nodes. What's your desired result? A rowset is not hierarchical, so some sort of choice has to be made about how to map elements and attributes to columns.

Comment: @DC07 *was cut off for some reason*: It was not indented. XML will not be displayed unless it is marked as `code` (backticks or indentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code provides some templates to read values out of any location into a flat table. Add missing columns yourself. That should be easy.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Report>
 <P>
    <Data>
      <Cust custID="A" custName="B" />
    </Data>
  </P>
  <H>
    <Data1>
      <Seats>
        <Seat id="abc" value="123" />
        <Date depart="abc1" arrive="1231" />
        <Records>
          <Record recID="C" col2="D" />
        </Records>
      </Seats>
      <Seats>
        <Seat id="xyz" value="756" />
        <Date depart="asd" arrive="6781" />
        <Records>
          <Record recID="1" col2="6" />
          <Record recID="2" col2="7" />
        </Records>
      </Seats>
    </Data1>
    <Data2>
      <S id="1" value="eco" />
      <S id="2" value="bus" />
    </Data2>
    <Data3>
      <Guest id="100" value="aaa" recID="C" />
      <Guest id="101" value="bbb" recID="1" />
      <Guest id="102" value="ccc" recID="2" />
    </Data3>
  </H>
</Report>';
```

--the query reads meta data out of the `@xml` directly and nested data out of derived tables via `.nodes()`

```
 select @xml.value('(/Report/P/Data/Cust/@custID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerID
       ,@xml.value('(/Report/P/Data/Cust/@custName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerName
       ,B.Seat.value('(Seat/@id)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SeatId
       ,B1.Record.value('@recID','nvarchar(max)') AS SeatRecordId
       ,C.S.value('@id','int') AS S_Id
       ,D.Guest.value('@id','int') AS Guest_Id
 INTO #FlatTable
 FROM @xml.nodes('/Report/H') AS A(DataNode)
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data1/Seats') AS B(Seat)
 OUTER APPLY B.Seat.nodes('Records/Record') AS B1(Record) 
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data2/S') AS C(S) 
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data3/Guest') AS D(Guest);

 SELECT * FROM #FlatTable;
```

Once you've got the data in this flat table, you can use any kind of `SELECT...GROUP BY` to get this prepared for inserts into specific detail tables.

If this does not help you out, you must provide more information about your target structure.

### UPDATE

According to your comment you want to place the guest besides the Seat, linked via `@recID`. This can be done by reading this value into a *normal result set column* and then use this value within an `XQuery` predicate using `sql:column()`:

```
 select @xml.value('(/Report/P/Data/Cust/@custID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerID
       ,@xml.value('(/Report/P/Data/Cust/@custName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerName
       ,B.Seat.value('(Seat/@id)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SeatId
       ,B2.RecordId AS SeatRecordId
       ,B3.Guest.value('@id','int') AS Guest_Id
       ,C.S.value('@id','int') AS S_Id
 INTO #FlatTable
 FROM @xml.nodes('/Report/H') AS A(DataNode)
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data1/Seats') AS B(Seat)
 OUTER APPLY B.Seat.nodes('Records/Record') AS B1(Record) 
 OUTER APPLY (SELECT B1.Record.value('@recID','nvarchar(max)')) AS B2(RecordId)
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data3/Guest[@recID=sql:column("B2.RecordId")]') AS B3(Guest)
 OUTER APPLY A.DataNode.nodes('Data2/S') AS C(S);
```

The result for this (don't know how you want to handle `<S>` values)

```
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| CustomerID | CustomerName | SeatId | SeatRecordId | Guest_Id | S_Id |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | abc    | C            | 100      | 1    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | abc    | C            | 100      | 2    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | xyz    | 1            | 101      | 1    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | xyz    | 1            | 101      | 2    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | xyz    | 2            | 102      | 1    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
| A          | B            | xyz    | 2            | 102      | 2    |
+------------+--------------+--------+--------------+----------+------+
```

Comment: hi Shnugo, yes this is what I'm after more or less. the rest can be worked out with SQL I suppose. The problem is, that for example Seat id "abc" in reality only applies to Guest id "100". Join via the record id (i added this to the xml..as it was missing). In this result everything is cross applied with each other

Comment: @DC07 Okay, this will get a little more complicated, but you find a solution in my update